# Stopping a textbox displaying NaN

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have got a text box that displays the result of two others multiplied together, before anything is in-putted the box displays NaN, is there a way to have it display "0" or even remain empty before anything multiplied.

```
Dim thick1 As Double
Dim tb8 As Double
Dim result As Double
thick1 = Val(thickness1.Text)
tb8 = Val(TextBox8.Text)
result = thick1 / tb8
TextBox30.Text = FormatNumber(result, 3)
```

^ the above code is what I am using for the text box.

Comment: Stop using VAL it isnt the same VAL as VB6.  Use TryParse instead, and you need to test that tb8 is non zero.  where is this code located, an event procedure maybe?  That might be the NaN issue.

Answer (score 0):

This would appear to be code in an event or form load that it is automatically running.  If the textboxes do not yet have values, then `result = thick1 / tb8` will result in Nan (not a Number) because you cannot divide by zero.

Again, assuming an event or something:

```
  If tb8 = 0 then
     Exit Sub
  else
     result = thick1 / tb8
     TextBox30.Text = result.ToString("G3")  

  End if
```

In addition to dumping VAL for TryParse, consider turning Option Explicit on

Comment: VB will give `result` (and the other variables) the default value for a `Double`, which is 0.0, when they are declared.  The issue was division by zero.

Answer (score 0):

Another way, try this:

```
TextBox30.Text = FormatNumber(result, 3).Tostring("n0")
```

I think it should displays a 0 even if number is not present (like a `NaN` string)

[MSDN: The Numeric ("N") Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#NFormatString)

If not, then try this else:

```
TextBox30.Text = FormatNumber(result, 3).ToString("0")
```

> "0"  Zero placeholder
>
> Replaces the zero with the corresponding digit if one is present; otherwise, zero appears in the result string.

[MSDN: Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Dim result As Double
Dim thick1 As Double = CDbl(thickness1.Text)
Dim tb8 As Double = CDbl(TextBox8.Text)
If IsNumeric(thick1) AndAlso IsNumeric(tb8) AndAlso tb8 <> 0 Then
    result = thick1 / tb8
    TextBox30.Text = result.ToString("G3")
End If
```